# How can I authenticate a Reddit user for my application?

Tags: java, oauth, reddit

I am making a desktop application for Reddit in Java. I want to let users log in to their Reddit account via my application so that they can do things on Reddit. I know that I need to get access tokens and whatnot but I don't know how to go through the process of doing that. Whenever I have accessed the API previously, it has been in Python using PRAW, so I would manually enter in the client id and client secret - obviously I can't be doing this for a professional application. I'd appreciate it if anyone would guide me through the process of authenticating the user and how to receive and use the access token.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use oauth apis. There is a sample integration for reddit. https://www.e4developer.com/2018/11/04/reddit-api-authentication-with-java-spring/

also there are developer guide for oauth in reddit page
https://reddit.com/dev/api/oauth

Reddit github page have good documentation
https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2